# Regex in Python - Extracting message from Tweet Data in a CSV file

Tags: python, regex

I have a CSV file named `tweets.csv`.

From this file I want to extract just the message details.
Within the file there are 9 headers;

```
id,link,content,date,retweets,favorites,mentions,hashtags,geo
```

An example of one tweet;

```
1698308935,https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1698308935,Be sure to tune in and watch Donald Trump on Late Night with David Letterman as he presents the Top Ten List tonight!,2009-05-04 20:54:25,500,868,,,
```

I want to extract the content for each tweet in the file.
Using regex I am struggling to identify the content data;

I have tried the below code;

```py
f1 = open("tweets.csv","r")
for line in f1:
    id = re.findall(r"status/d",line)
    print(id.group())
```

Also the below but with not much success - I am new to this and would appreciate any assistance.

```
pattern = re.findall(r"status/d","tweets.csv")
#print(pattern())
```

Comment: Consider using [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for this type of work since it is the easiest way and the cleanest too. No need to do this from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this regex pattern `^\d*,[\w:/.]*,([^,]*)`. It will capture any chars except comma after the second commas. See this [demo and explanations](https://regexr.com/6aou4).

Another solution which is also the easiest to use is by using [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) library.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('tweets.csv')
print(df['content'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a CSV file, you need no Pandas package, use the `csv` module:

```py
with open("tweets.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    with open("tweets_contents.txt", "w") as out_file:
        for row in reader:
            out_file.write(row[2] + "\n")
```

Here, `row[2]` is the third column in your CSV file, it will be saved in a *tweets_contents.txt* file.

If your files are in UTF8 encoding, pass `encoding="utf8"` argument to `open`.